# Following the initial ReactDOM.render is the whole DOM ready when the componentDidMount methods start firing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class CompA extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("a");
    debugger;
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Component A</div>;
  }
}

class CompB extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("b");
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Component B</div>;
  }
}

class CompC extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("c");
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Component C</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("App");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="top-level-component">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <CompA />
        <CompB />
        <CompC />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Link to Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwzk4rj5j)

I have three questions:

**Question 1**

In the initial render from `ReactDOM.render()`, only a single append operation happens (i.e. the `#top-level-component` DOM element, which already contains all of its children, is appended to the `#root` DOM element), instead of appending `#top-level-component` to the `#root`, and then appending its children's DOM elements to the `#top-level-component`DOM element. Correct?

**Question 2**

The `componentDidMount` methods of the components fire after that single append operation has happened, bottom to top, in order, meaning the console will log

```
a
b
c
App
```

This means that when the `componentDidMount` of `CompA` fires, the **whole** DOM is ready and if it's necessary, it can possibly query the DOM for one of its siblings. Correct?

**Question 3**

Following the above, is it generally safe (meaning in component mountings that happen later, after the initial `ReactDOM.render()`) to assume that when we have some sibling components, when the first sibling's `componentDidMount` fires the other siblings' DOM representations are already flushed into the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1:** Correct. React will only append to the DOM once it has the full virtual-DOM calculated and ready to be inserted. This is the absolute final stage of the rendering process.

**Q2:** Correct.

**Q3:** If I understood your question correctly, yes. Again, like in question 1, DOM flushing only happens ONCE during any one render.

I suggest you take a look at the [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) part of the official documentation for more info about how React builds the virtual-DOM.

Also, if you want to play around with `ReactDOM.render()`, you could do:

```
const func = () => {
  console.log("ReactDOM.render() fired!");
  return <App />;
}

ReactDOM.render(func(), document.getElementById("root"));
```

to see when and how many times it fires.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time!